# How to add a MIME handler to Firefox and Internet Explorer from an installer

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, mime, nsis

I'm looking to create an installer that will add a handler for a MIME type in Firefox and Explorer. The installer I will be using will be either INNO (a.k.a Oh Nooo!) or NSIS.

I'm looking for for how Mozilla and Microsoft recommend adding the handler. So far all I have been able to find for Firefox is how to Add/Remove/Augment manually which no matter how simple is something I would like to hide from the user.

I have seen an example where someone modifies an XML file in Firefox's configuration, is this how the installers are accomplishing this?